# Copy key values from NameValueCollection to Generic Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, namevaluecollection

Trying to copy values from an existing NameValueCollection object to a Dictionary. I have the following code below to do that but seems the Add does not accept that my keys and values are as Strings

```
IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
public void copyFromNameValueCollection (NameValueCollection a)
{
    foreach (var k in a.AllKeys)
    { 
        dict.Add(k, a[k]);
    }  
}
```

**Note:** NameValueCollection contains String keys and values and so I simply want to provide here a method to allow copying of those to a **generic** dictionary.

Comment: It's very confusing, because presumably this is in a generic *type* declaring `TKey`, `TValue` type parameters - and your *method* declares those type parameters too. Add to that the fact that the keys will always be strings... so what do you expect to happen if TKey is (say) Guid?

Comment: I need a generic dictionary to work with. Please note that this is in building a serializable dictionary class, that also allows for copying of keys and values from NameValueCollection objects

Comment: Again, what would this do if TKey isn't string?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use generics here since you can't assign `string`s to some arbitrary generic type:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public void copyFrom(NameValueCollection a)
{
            foreach (var k in a.AllKeys)
            { 
                dict.Add(k, a[k]);
            }  
}
```

although you should probably create a method to create a new dictionary instead:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection col)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var k in col.AllKeys)
    { 
        dict.Add(k, col[k]);
    }  
    return dict;
}
```

which you can use like:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = //
var dictionary = nvc.ToDictionary();
```

If you want a general way of converting the strings in the collection into the required key/value types, you can use type converters:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this NameValueCollection col)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    var keyConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TKey));
    var valueConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TValue));

    foreach(string name in col)
    {
        TKey key = (TKey)keyConverter.ConvertFromString(name);
        TValue value = (TValue)valueConverter.ConvertFromString(col[name]);
        dict.Add(key, value);
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: NameValueCollection has String keys and values. I want to be able to copy those over to a generic dictionary.

Comment: @Kobojunkie - You can't copy it to a generic dictionary, since the key and value types can be anything. You can only copy it to a `Dictionary<string, string>` or one with less-derived key or value types e.g. `object`.

Comment: @Kobojunkie - Of course it's correct - you can't say `T obj = "abc"` for **any** type `T`. It will only compile if `T` is `string` or a less-derived type. You could convert your strings to the target type, but that isn't clear from your question.

Comment: @Kobojunkie - I've added a general way of converting the keys/values in the collection into the target types.

Comment: I thought you said earlier that it was not possible?

Comment: @Kobojunkie - It's not possible without converting the strings. The code in your question is trying to insert strings into a dictionary with unknown key and value types, which is not possible.

Comment: This answer doesn't quite work if NameValueCollection has a null key - which is perfectly acceptable according to the NameValueCollection documentation. Before inserting key into Dictionary check if null and insert empty string I guess?

Answer (score 83):

Extension method plus linq:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection nvc) {
    return nvc.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => nvc[k]);
 }

 //example
 var dictionary = nvc.ToDictionary();
```

Answer (score 26):

```
parameters.AllKeys.ToDictionary(t => t, t => parameters[t]);
```

Comment: Love this. Thank you!

Comment: `k` makes more sense than `t` to represent "key"

Answer (score 5):

Use LINQ:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection collection)
{
    return collection.Cast<string>().ToDictionary(k => k, v => collection[v]);
}
```

Usage:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dic = nv.ToDictionary();
```

Answer (score 3):

Super-Short Version

```
var dataNvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data);
var dataCollection = dataNvc.AllKeys.ToDictionary(o => o, o => dataNvc[o]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your dictionary is always going to contain strings, specify it to contain strings instead of making your class generic:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

With this, things will "just work" as written (without the generic method specification).

If you need this to be a generic class, and hold generic data, you need some way to convert from `string` to `TKey` and `string` to `TValue`.  You could provide delegates to your copy method to do this:

```
public void CopyFrom(NameValueCollection a, Func<string, TKey> keyConvert, Func<string, TValue> valueConvert)
{
    foreach(var k in a.AllKeys)
    {
         dict.Add(keyConvert(k), valueConvert(a[k]));
    }
}
```

You would then need to pass a delegate in that would perform the conversion from string to `TValue` and string to `TKey`.

Comment: This answer should mention that `NameValueCollection`s can have null keys, and this mismatch must be accounted for in converting to a dictionary, which has a non null key invariant

Comment: The Dictionary is not always going to contain strings. I simply want it to also be able to copy values from NameValueCollection object in this method.

Comment: @Kobojunkie Then you need the second mechanism - You need to convert from string to your types

Comment: That is what I am seeking help with here. How do I convert the string keys and values in the NameValueCollection to the generic type in this method so I can load those to my generic dictionary object

Comment: @Kobojunkie There is no "general purpose" way to do this - you need some type of method to do the conversion.  My second option shows how to write the method so this can be passed in as a delegate.

Comment: Again, the reason for this question is so I can get help with that "option". I need a way to, in my generic Dictionary class, provide a way for copying of data from NameValueCollection objects as well. That is what I am trying to find here.

Answer (score 0):

You should not forget about EqualityComparer. But it is not a public property. So, you should use reflection to get it.

```
public static IEqualityComparer GetEqualityComparer(this NameObjectCollectionBase nameObjectCollection)
  {
  PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(NameObjectCollectionBase).GetProperty("Comparer", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
  return (IEqualityComparer)propertyInfo.GetValue(nameObjectCollection);
  }

public static IEqualityComparer<string> GetEqualityComparer(this NameValueCollection nameValueCollection)
  {
  return (IEqualityComparer<string>)((NameObjectCollectionBase)nameValueCollection).GetEqualityComparer();
  }

public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection nameValueCollection)
  {
  Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
    nameValueCollection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(x => x, x => nameValueCollection[x], nameValueCollection.GetEqualityComparer());
  return dictionary;
  }
```